# Is it possible to supply power to a system if the transformer is "dead"?

Tags: transformer

Up front: I am totally clueless.

I have a Pfaff tiptronic 1171 sewing machine. The service people say the transformer is dead and no one makes a replacement. It has a circuit board, a jack for the foot pedal, and a power input cord.

Information on back tag: 115v  60Hz max15w 8.0w 0  7.5A

If the hand wheel is turned, all the stitches work.

Is there some work around to get the motor and foot pedal running? I can live without the light, bobbin sensor, and stop position.

I don't know if this is the right place to ask. If not, can anyone point me in the right direction of where to ask?

[image]

Comment: There are places that rewind transformers.   It's common in vintage audio.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: From some sleuthing online it looks like old equipment using standard (non switching) transformers. If you can figure out the winding voltages you should be able to rig up a replacement. There's lots of transformer manufacturers.

Comment: Can you provide a photograph of the label? The figures don't seem to figure.

Comment: There are sites like [fixya](https://www.fixya.com/support/t17317885-pfaff_tiptronic_1071_1171_suddenly).

Comment: User's guide for reference: https://www.pfaff.com/globalassets/pfaff/Resources/de-DE/Retired-Machines/Tiptronic_1071_1171-manual-DE.PDF

Comment: If you don't want to somehow disconnect the old transformer from its PCB&rectifiers, you can attach the rectified outputs of a similar spec replacement to the buffer capacitors.

Comment: Lost - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it wasn't the answer to your original question. It was additional information, so it has been added to your question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. || Since you asked the question, unless you are writing the *full & final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself & don't need further help) please don't use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead, to add more information / clarification, please [edit] the question. Or comment to respond to a minor point. || Please see the [tour] & [help] for more rules. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The transformer should be easy to replace, though you might have to substitute *two* transformers (one for each winding, (e.g., [this](https://www.grainger.com/category/electrical/transformers-ups-power-supplies/transformers/class-2-transformers?attrs=Output%20Voltage%20-%20Transformer%7C10V%20AC&filters=attrs) and [this](https://www.grainger.com/search/electrical/transformers-ups-power-supplies/transformers/class-2-transformers?tv_optin=true&searchQuery=12%20vac%20transformer&searchBar=true&tier=Not%20Applicable) from Grainger, though you likely can find them for less elsewhere), if you cannot find an exact match. According to [KochShop.dk](https://kochshop.dk/PFAFF-PCB-transformer?search=pfaff), the windings are:

```
Pin 1-4: 230 VAC primary [if your mains are 120 VAC, you'd want 120 VAC primary] 
Pin 6-10: 10V 2 VA 
Pin 7-9: 12V 0.3 VA
```

Both are quite low power, and a transformer of higher current rating would be acceptable.

Also check for *other* causes of the issue, e.g. [a blown fuse under the baseplate](https://www.fixya.com/support/t17317885-pfaff_tiptronic_1071_1171_suddenly), since transformers rarely fail on their own.
BTW, the **full shop manual** can be found at https://www.opweb.de/english/company/Pfaff/1171 .

Comment: Found that "KockShop" aswell, but didn't mention it because it's for 1071 rather then 1171. Might be the same tough.

Answer (score 0):

When there is a suspected blown transformer you can trace out the power supply circuit which is usually just bridge rectifier and electrolytic caps .Use your lab regulated supply and carefully apply voltages across the big eltec caps.Keep an eye on current consumption starting at zero going up to 1.4 times the transformer sec winding voltage. Doing this means that you can have good confidence that the PCB is good before committing to transformer replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the photo (which should be edited into the question) there may be a 109°C thermal cutoff associated with the transformer. If you look carefully at the transformer there may be a lump that indicates such a component. I would expect it to be in series with the mains primary.

There may be some other issue that has caused the transformer to overheat.